# Deadlock avoidance algorithm

Tags: algorithm, operating-system, deadlock

I'm finding all algorithm to solve Deadlock, but I just find Banker’s Algorithm.
Where do I can find other algorithm  to solve this problem?
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Deadlock avoidance is not something that can be isolated to individual (smaller) pieces of a larger system; it must be systemic (applied throughout the entire system of smaller pieces).

There are only 2 approaches that I know of:

a) "global lock ordering". The basic idea is to ensure all locks are acquired in order; which requires establishing an order for all possible locks in the entire system. For example; if one part of the system has a lock protecting a FIFO queue and another part of the system has an array with a lock per array entry; then you might decide that the order is "FIFO queue lock; then array entry lock/s in order of array index".

b) No locks. This can be as simple as not having any threads; or as complex as using a "shared nothing, message passing" model (where each piece of data belongs to a specific thread and no other threads can access it, and all other threads have to ask the owner to act on their behalf).